# How to fix terraform error var.zaccounts is list of string with 1 element

Tags: terraform

I want a list of strings and one of my accounts (backed by tfstate) happens to have 1 in the list.  I am confused why you can loop over list of size 1.  The code is simply

```
resource "datadog_dashboard" "hq" {
  for_each = var.zaccounts
  ...
```

and then the var is

```
variable "zaccounts" {
    type = list(string)
    default = []
    description = "List of accounts"
}
```

var.auto.vars is

```
zaccounts = [ "zmainbranch" ]
```

In the example, when we run there is only ONE tfstate, ONE account and a developer created a framework which basically creates the above tf files so we are not using workspaces or anything else.  It is a pretty simple example.

I am not sure what to try here as the error is counter intuitive saying exactly what you should be able to do in any programming language - ie. you should be able to loop over a list of size 1.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for_each` meta argument can work only with [maps and sets](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#basic-syntax):

> If a resource or module block includes a `for_each` argument whose value is a map or a set of strings, Terraform creates one instance for each member of that map or set.

So you could either define the variable as a set of strings or perform a conversion to a set:

```
resource "datadog_dashboard" "hq" {
  for_each = toset(var.zaccounts)
  ...
}
```

As mentioned, alternatively you can redefine the variable:

```
variable "zaccounts" {
    type = set(string)
    default = []
    description = "List of accounts"
}
```

In that case, you would not need the `toset` built-in function, the code you have can remain as-is.

Comment: Side note: `list` type is accepted for `for_each` in dynamic blocks despite not for `resource` blocks.

Comment: Unfortunately even `toset` failed for me with no reasonable explanation why. Ultimately `map(string)` is what worked, referencing `each.value` instead of `each.key` in the `for_each`. There are other benefits to using `map` per the docs and [discussed here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/alternative-design-to-avoid-use-of-target/42318/2)

Comment: It depends probably on the type of variable you were using.